# Insert a row on top of the data with day name of columns name

Tags: sql, sql-server

i create dynamic table date wise based on the user selection
lets suppose user select date from 15-9 to 19-9
so i create table  as below in which i have dates as columns

i create this query as example to reproduce this table

```
with dates ( [15/09/2018],[16/09/2018],[17/09/2018],[18/09/2018],[19/09/2018]) as 
(  select  '1' ,'0','1','1','1' union all
   select  '1' ,'0','0','1','1' union all
   select  '1' ,'0','1','0','1' union all
   select  '0' ,'0','1','1','1' union all
   select  '0' ,'0','0','1','0'
)
select  [15/09/2018],[16/09/2018],[17/09/2018],[18/09/2018],[19/09/2018]  from dates
```

now i want to create a temp table in SQL in which i have extra row which has the name day of the column header
like 15/09/2018 day name is wed and so on

| [15/09/2018] | [16/09/2018] | [16/09/2018] | [16/09/2018] | [16/09/2018] |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Wednesday | Thursday | Friday | Saturday | Sunday |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

not sure what to search and how to do it

the above query is just a query so you can create table which i am using (as example) , the dates in column header are dynamic so i can not hard code them , so i need some query which read column header , get day name from it and add it in row under that column

Comment: While this is a strange idea, your SQL is fine as is.  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f381cd3e232c5d69966497fa428ee883

Comment: If you're asking if you can query the column names (which are in the form of dates) and then determine the associated day name of that 'date', this is just a bad idea.  You must have a different overall requirement that is driving this strange design.  It's probably best to just change the design.  You could certainly try to use information_schema to derive that detail.

Comment: its very simple requirement , i have data save as date wise , now i just want a row which has the dayname of that date

Comment: i want the SQL to be dynamic to get date2 table(this could be temp table ) from date table

Comment: @Ahteshamulhaq, add an `OrderByColumn` in the inner query (`... select  0, 'Wednesday' ,'Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday' union all 1, select  '1' ,'0','1','1','1' union all ...`) and use this column to order the results.

Comment: @Zhorov date2 is the result i want to achieve ,issue is to insert the row , i can order it later

Comment: If ordering is not the issue to solve then you have a working solution already in your question, so it's not clear exactly what you are asking?

Comment: @stu i have updated the question , i have the date table and i want to create a temp table in which i have row which has the name day of the column header

Comment: @Ahteshamulhaq *I want to create a temp table* - that statement doesn't appear in your question anywhere, at least not before you just edited.

Comment: @Stu i added it later when i updated

Answer (score 0):

You can create a temp table with the column names as part of your select using `select into`:

```
with dates2(...)
select
[15/09/2018],[16/09/2018],[17/09/2018],[18/09/2018],[19/09/2018]
into #MyTempTable
from dates2
```

Comment: as i mention that column header are kind of dynamic so we need to read it dynamic :(

Comment: Then it's not clear exactly what your question is asking for. There's nothing in your question apart from a specific query you currently have - you haven't explained this well at all unfortunately, there's nothing about where your data comes from or even the schema or content of your table, as written it appears you already have what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can create the table, then use information_schema to obtain the column names, which can be used to generate the day names for each column name, then `PIVOT` that result into a row to be `UNION`'d into the data.

```
CREATE TABLE test (
   [15/09/2018]   varchar(12)
 , [16/09/2018]   varchar(12)
 , [17/09/2018]   varchar(12)
 , [18/09/2018]   varchar(12)
 , [19/09/2018]   varchar(12)
);

with dates2 (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5) as 
(
   select  '1' ,'0','1','1','1' union all
   select  '1' ,'0','0','1','1' union all
   select  '1' ,'0','1','0','1' union all
   select  '0' ,'0','1','1','1' union all
   select  '0' ,'0','0','1','0'
)
INSERT INTO test
select * from dates2
;

-- Adjusted to order by `ord` and to use `UNION ALL` to prevent removal of non-unique rows.

WITH cte AS (
         SELECT 1 AS ord, * FROM test
          UNION ALL
         SELECT 0 AS ord,
           [1], [2], [3], [4], [5]
         FROM
         (
           SELECT ORDINAL_POSITION, DATENAME(dw, CONVERT(DATE, COLUMN_NAME, 103)) AS colname
             FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns
            WHERE table_schema = 'dbo'
              AND table_name   = 'test'
         ) AS SourceTable
         PIVOT
         (
           MAX( colname )
           FOR ORDINAL_POSITION IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5])
         ) AS PivotTable
     )
SELECT * FROM cte ORDER BY ord
;
```

and to create the temp table:

```
WITH cte AS (
         SELECT 1 AS ord, * FROM test
          UNION ALL
         SELECT 0 AS ord,
           [1], [2], [3], [4], [5]
         FROM
         (
           SELECT ORDINAL_POSITION, DATENAME(dw, CONVERT(DATE, COLUMN_NAME, 103)) AS colname
             FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns
            WHERE table_schema = 'dbo'
              AND table_name   = 'test'
         ) AS SourceTable
         PIVOT
         (
           MAX( colname )
           FOR ORDINAL_POSITION IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5])
         ) AS PivotTable
     )
SELECT * INTO #TmpTable FROM cte
;

SELECT * FROM #TmpTable ORDER BY ord;
```

The test case:

[Working Test Case. See the last panels](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b3c1747cc4c53874c4799884ed34bb42)

Result:

[image]